# Final program return from a function in C

Tags: c, function, error-handling, return-value, void

I'd like to end a program with error message and return value 100 from inside of function:

```
    void readSize(int *rows, int *cols) {
        while(!(scanf("%d %d", rows, cols))) {
            fputs("Error: Incorrect input!\n", stderr);
            return 100;
        }
    }
```

I want that return to return 100 like if it was from the main() if you know what I mean. I tried goto, but it can't jump between functions. Any ideas?

Comment: You want `exit(100)`.

Comment: @Blaze That was on purpose to show, what I'd like to do.

Comment: Also, you've got some problems with your `scanf` call.  I think you want `if`, not `while`, and the condition should be `!= 2`, not (in effect) `== 0`.  (My point is that if `scanf` returns 1, or -1, or in fact anything other than 2, that's a failure.)

Comment: @SteveSummit Thanks! I'll leave it there in case someone searches for this in a similar phrasing later. :)

Comment: @SteveSummit Both the question and answer is simple, but I think you should write that as an answer.

Comment: @tomashauser yes, you should not correct the code that was posted (unless it wasn't the code you were using) or the question won't make any sense.

Comment: Is there a way how to flag a comment as a correct answer to my problem? I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Steve Summit in the comments. Just use `exit(100)`

The function you're looking for is `exit()`. As argument you pass the return code you want to return. There are standard macros for this, like `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE` but you can choose an `int` of your choice. When used in function `main`, `exit(x)` is equivalent to `return x`.

You can read about the exit function here: https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.4.4

Another detail is that `while(!(scanf("%d %d", rows, cols)))` is wrong. If both `row` and `cols` are successfully assigned, `scanf` will return 2. Sure, what you have written will be treated as success if it returns 2, but it will do the same if it returns 1, which should be treated as a failure. Instead, do `while(!(scanf("%d %d", rows, cols)) == 2)`, or even better if it suits your needs, consider a combination of `fgets` and `sscanf` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58403537/6699433)